# How to run task schedular programatically using "run whether user is logged on or not"

Tags: c#

I have written a code in c# to schedule a task programatically with all the required fields(frequency,recur,monthly or weekly etc). It's working fine with "Run when the user is logged on option".

But I need my code to schedule a task under "Run whether the user is logged on or not". Please provide me with a solution. I have used the following code.

```
private void btn_Build_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

     //   string xmlOutput = txt_DestinationPath.Text + "\\" + txtTaskName.Text + ".xml";
        string xmlOutput = "d:\\BuildSchedule.xml";
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlTextWriter.Create(xmlOutput))
        {
            string frequency = "Once";
            string sourceControl="";
            int recur = 1 ;
            if (txtRecur.Text != string.Empty) 
              recur = Convert.ToInt32(txtRecur.Text);

            string selectedDays="";
            string allDays = "mon";
            string selectedMonths = "";
            string allMonths = "JAN,FEB,MAR,APR,MAY,JUN,JUL,AUG,SEP,OCT,NOV,DEC";

            if (radio_TFS.Checked == true)
                sourceControl = "TFS";
            else if (radio_VSS.Checked == true)
                sourceControl = "VSS";

            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement("ConfigurationSettings");
            writer.WriteStartElement("Credentials");
            writer.WriteElementString("URI",txtURI.Text.ToString());
            writer.WriteElementString("UserName","");
            writer.WriteElementString("Password", "");
            writer.WriteElementString("SourceControl", sourceControl);
            writer.WriteElementString("TaskName", "buildSchedule");
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteStartElement("Schedule");
            if (radioDaily.Checked == true)
                frequency = "Daily";
            else if (radioWeekly.Checked == true)
            {
                frequency = "Weekly";
               foreach (string row in listDays.CheckedItems)
                    selectedDays = selectedDays + row + ",";
               if (selectedDays != string.Empty)
                   selectedDays = selectedDays.Remove(selectedDays.Length - 1, 1);
               else
                   selectedDays = allDays;

            }
            else if (radioMonthly.Checked == true)
            {
                frequency = "Monthly";
                selectedMonths = string.Empty;
                foreach (string row in listMonths.CheckedItems)
                    selectedMonths = selectedMonths + row + ",";
                if (selectedMonths != string.Empty)
                    selectedMonths = selectedMonths.Remove(selectedMonths.Length - 1, 1);
                else
                    selectedMonths = allMonths;

            }

            writer.WriteElementString("Frequency", frequency);

            writer.WriteElementString("Recur", recur.ToString());
            writer.WriteElementString("SelectedDays", selectedDays.ToString());
            writer.WriteElementString("SelectedMonths", selectedMonths.ToString());

            writer.WriteElementString("Date", Convert.ToString(dtpDate.Value.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")));
            writer.WriteElementString("Time", Convert.ToString(dtpTime.Value.ToString("HH:mm:ss")));
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteStartElement("PathAndFiles");
            writer.WriteElementString("ServerPath", txtServerPath.Text);
            writer.WriteElementString("SolutionFilePath", txtSolutionPath.Text);
            writer.WriteElementString("DestinationFilePath", txt_DestinationPath.Text);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }


        schedule1(xmlOutput);

    }

    void schedule1(string xmlPath)
    {

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(xmlPath);
        root = doc.DocumentElement;
        string TaskName = root.GetElementsByTagName("TaskName")[0].InnerText;
        string  frequency = root.GetElementsByTagName("Frequency")[0].InnerText;
        string sb = root.GetElementsByTagName("Date")[0].InnerText + " " + root.GetElementsByTagName("Time")[0].InnerText;
        // func(TaskName);
        using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
        {
            string[] path1 = Environment.CurrentDirectory.Split('\\');
            int count1 = path1.Length;
            count1 = count1 - 3;
            string path = "";
            for (int index = 0; index < count1; index++)
                path = path + path1[index] + "\\";

            path = path + "DownloadAndBuild\\bin\\Debug\\DownloadAndBuild.exe";
            if(frequency=="Once")
            {
                ////Task t = ts.AddTask(taskName,
                ////                    new TimeTrigger() { StartBoundary = Convert.ToDateTime(sb) + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), Enabled = true },
                ////                    //new ExecAction(@"D:\TTS-mapped\BuildAutomation\DownloadAndBuild\bin\Debug\DownloadAndBuild.exe", null, null));
                ////                    new ExecAction(@pathExe, null, null));

                Task t = ts.AddTask(TaskName, new TimeTrigger() { StartBoundary = Convert.ToDateTime(sb) + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), Enabled = true },
                              new ExecAction(path, null, null), null, null, TaskLogonType.InteractiveToken);



            }
            else if (frequency == "Daily") 
            {
                ////if (txtRecur.Text != "")
                ////{
                ////    Task t = ts.AddTask(taskName,
                ////        new DailyTrigger() { StartBoundary = Convert.ToDateTime(sb) + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), Enabled = true, DaysInterval = Convert.ToInt16(txtRecur.Text) },
                ////        //new ExecAction(@"D:\TTS-mapped\BuildAutomation\DownloadAndBuild\bin\Debug\DownloadAndBuild.exe",null,null));//C:\Users\rukmanipriya_s\Desktop\TFS_18thJuly\TFS\DownloadAndBuild\bin\Debug
                ////        new ExecAction(@pathExe, null, null));

                ////}
                ////else
                ////{
                ////    Task t = ts.AddTask(taskName,
                ////        new DailyTrigger() { StartBoundary = Convert.ToDateTime(sb) + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), Enabled = true },
                ////        //new ExecAction(@"D:\TTS-mapped\BuildAutomation\DownloadAndBuild\bin\Debug\DownloadAndBuild.exe",null,null));//C:\Users\rukmanipriya_s\Desktop\TFS_18thJuly\TFS\DownloadAndBuild\bin\Debug
                ////        new ExecAction(@pathExe, null, null));

                ////}

                //if (txtRecur.Text != "")
                //{

                //    Task t = ts.AddTask(taskName, new DailyTrigger(1) { StartBoundary = Convert.ToDateTime(sb) + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), Enabled = true, DaysInterval = Convert.ToInt16(txtRecur.Text) }, new ExecAction(path, null, null), null, null, TaskLogonType.InteractiveToken);
                //}
                //else
                //{
                //    Task t = ts.AddTask(taskName, new DailyTrigger(1) { StartBoundary = Convert.ToDateTime(sb) + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), Enabled = true}, new ExecAction(path, null, null), null, null, TaskLogonType.InteractiveToken);
                //}

                Task t = ts.AddTask(TaskName, new DailyTrigger(1) { StartBoundary = Convert.ToDateTime(sb) + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), Enabled = true, DaysInterval = Convert.ToInt16(root.GetElementsByTagName("Recur")[0].InnerText) }, new ExecAction(path, null, null), null, null, TaskLogonType.InteractiveToken);

            }
            else if (frequency == "Weekly")
            {
                DaysOfTheWeek dw = DaysOfTheWeek.Sunday - 1;
                string[] str = root.GetElementsByTagName("SelectedDays")[0].InnerText.Split(',');
                int count = str.Length;

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    if (str[i] == "mon")
                        dw = dw | DaysOfTheWeek.Monday;
                    else if (str[i] == "tue")
                        dw = dw | DaysOfTheWeek.Tuesday;
                    else if (str[i] == "wed")
                        dw = dw | DaysOfTheWeek.Wednesday;
                    else if (str[i] == "thu")
                        dw = dw | DaysOfTheWeek.Thursday;
                    else if (str[i] == "fri")
                        dw = dw | DaysOfTheWeek.Friday;
                    else if (str[i] == "sat")
                        dw = dw | DaysOfTheWeek.Saturday;
                    else
                        dw = dw | DaysOfTheWeek.Sunday;
                }
               // Task t = ts.AddTask(taskName,
               //new WeeklyTrigger() { StartBoundary = Convert.ToDateTime(sb) + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), Enabled = true, DaysOfWeek = dw, WeeksInterval = Convert.ToInt16(root.GetElementsByTagName("Recur")[0].InnerText) },
               ////new ExecAction(@"D:\TTS-mapped\BuildAutomation\DownloadAndBuild\bin\Debug\DownloadAndBuild.exe", null, null));
               //new ExecAction(@pathExe, null, null));
                Task t = ts.AddTask(TaskName, new WeeklyTrigger(DaysOfTheWeek.Sunday, 1) { StartBoundary = Convert.ToDateTime(sb) + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), Enabled = true, DaysOfWeek = dw, WeeksInterval = Convert.ToInt16(root.GetElementsByTagName("Recur")[0].InnerText) }, new ExecAction(path, null, null), null, null, TaskLogonType.InteractiveToken);

            }
            else if(frequency == "Monthly")
            {
                MonthsOfTheYear dw = MonthsOfTheYear.January - 1;
                string[] str = root.GetElementsByTagName("SelectedMonths")[0].InnerText.Split(',');
                int count = str.Length;

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    if (str[i] == "JAN")
                        dw = dw | MonthsOfTheYear.January;
                    else if (str[i] == "FEB")
                        dw = dw | MonthsOfTheYear.February;
                    else if (str[i] == "MAR")
                        dw = dw | MonthsOfTheYear.March;
                    else if (str[i] == "APR")
                        dw = dw | MonthsOfTheYear.April;
                    else if (str[i] == "MAY")
                        dw = dw | MonthsOfTheYear.May;
                    else if (str[i] == "JUN")
                        dw = dw | MonthsOfTheYear.June;
                    else if (str[i] == "JUL")
                        dw = dw | MonthsOfTheYear.July;
                    else if (str[i] == "AUG")
                        dw = dw | MonthsOfTheYear.August;
                    else if (str[i] == "SEP")
                        dw = dw | MonthsOfTheYear.September;
                    else if (str[i] == "OCT")
                        dw = dw | MonthsOfTheYear.October;
                    else if (str[i] == "NOV")
                        dw = dw | MonthsOfTheYear.November;
                    else
                        dw = dw | MonthsOfTheYear.December;
                }
                //Task t = ts.AddTask(taskName,
                //    new MonthlyTrigger { StartBoundary = Convert.ToDateTime(sb) + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), Enabled = true, MonthsOfYear = dw },
                //    //new ExecAction(@"D:\TTS-mapped\BuildAutomation\DownloadAndBuild\bin\Debug\DownloadAndBuild.exe", null, null));
                //    new ExecAction(@pathExe, null, null));

                Task t = ts.AddTask(TaskName, new MonthlyTrigger(1, MonthsOfTheYear.AllMonths) { StartBoundary = Convert.ToDateTime(sb) + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), Enabled = true, MonthsOfYear = dw }, new ExecAction(path, null, null), null, null, TaskLogonType.InteractiveToken);

            }

        }
    }
    void schedule(string xmlPath)
    {
         XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
         doc.Load(xmlPath);
        root = doc.DocumentElement;

        string frequency;
        string command;
        string date;
        int recur;
        string time;
        string selectedDays;
        string selectedMonths;
        string taskName;

        time = root.GetElementsByTagName("Time")[0].InnerText;
        date = root.GetElementsByTagName("Date")[0].InnerText;                                 
        frequency = root.GetElementsByTagName("Frequency")[0].InnerText;
        recur = Convert.ToInt32(root.GetElementsByTagName("Recur")[0].InnerText);
        selectedDays = root.GetElementsByTagName("SelectedDays")[0].InnerText;
        selectedMonths = root.GetElementsByTagName("SelectedMonths")[0].InnerText;
        taskName = root.GetElementsByTagName("TaskName")[0].InnerText;

        command = "SCHTASKS /Create /SC once /TN varun12 /ST 14:06:00 /SD 08/01/2012 /TR DownloadAndBuild.exe";
        int exit = FetchProjects.ExecuteCommand(command, 111110);
        if(frequency == "once")
              command = "SCHTASKS /Create /SC " + frequency + " /TN "+taskName+" /ST " + time + " /SD " + date+ " /TR D:\\demoBuild.bat";
          else if (frequency == "weekly" && selectedDays != string.Empty)
            command = "SCHTASKS /Create /SC " + frequency + " /MO " + recur + " /D " + selectedDays + " /TN " + taskName + " /ST " + time + " /SD " + date + " /TR D:\\demoBuild.bat";
        else if (frequency == "weekly" && selectedDays == string.Empty)
            command = "SCHTASKS /Create /SC " + frequency + " /MO " + recur + " /D *" + " /TN " + taskName + " /ST " + time + " /SD " + date + " /TR D:\\demoBuild.bat";
        else if(frequency == "monthly" && selectedMonths != string.Empty)
            command = "SCHTASKS /Create /SC " + frequency + " /M " + selectedMonths + " /TN " + taskName + " /ST " + time + " /SD " + date + " /TR D:\\demoBuild.bat";
        else if (frequency == "monthly" && selectedMonths == string.Empty)
            command = "SCHTASKS /Create /SC " + frequency + " /M *" + " /TN " + taskName + " /ST " + time + " /SD " + date + " /TR D:\\demoBuild.bat";
        else
            command = "SCHTASKS /Create /SC " + frequency + " /MO " + recur + " /TN " + taskName + " /ST " + time + " /SD " + date + " /TR D:\\demoBuild.bat";

        // command = "SCHTASKS /Create /SC once /TN varun /ST 18:47:00 /SD 07/26/2012 /TR D:\\demoBuild.bat";


    }
```

Comment: This is way too much code. Trim it down to a reproducable test case.

Answer (score 0):

WMI is a better way of programmatically creating new schedule items, and is far more flexible.

Take a look at [WMI Tasks: Scheduled Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394601%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the [Win32_ScheduledJob class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394399%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and if you've not used it before - [WMI .Net Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb404655.aspx)

Comment: You can do it in C#. That's the whole point. WMI has a managed interface. It's all done through the System.Management namespace. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb404655.aspx